# Regex expression to match string between two other strings

Tags: javascript, regex

Another hard regex in javascript:

I have this string:

```
    <td style="padding:0 2%">{% for product in products.pos01 %}    
<table class="box-item" item-editable="" style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px; width:32%;border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td style=" padding:10px 5px; vertical-align:top ">
<a href="**|product.url|**" class="button view-deal" style="padding:8px 10px; background-color: #fc5d26; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; text-align:center; color:#fff; font-size:12px;margin:0px; line-height:140%;text-transform:uppercase">view deal</a></div></td></tr></table>{% if (loop.index0-2) is divisibleby 3 %}</td></tr><tr>
<td style="padding:0 2%">{% endif %}{% endfor %}
 </td>
```

I'm trying to get content inside any loops from the string {% for ... %} and {% endfor %}

I've tried with, but can't get

> /({% for (!?%})+ %})((!?endfor)*){% endfor %}/gm

but didn't work

Comment: Perhaps, [this one](https://regex101.com/r/oV7rL2/1): `\{%\s*for[\s\S]*?%}([\s\S]*?)\{%\s*endfor\s*%}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

`{% for [^\0]+?{% endfor %}`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/gX9hQ0/2)

Explanation:

```
{% for            # search for text `{% for `
[^\0]+?           # while not input's end
{% endfor %}      # search for the next `{% endfor %}`
```

---

Or, if you want groups:

```
{% (for [^\0]+?)%}([^\0]+?){% endfor %}
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/gX9hQ0/5)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you suppose to use a pattern similar to this

**Regex**

```
(?<={% for[^%]*%})((?:.|\n)*)(?={% endfor %})
```

**Explanation**

`(?<={% for[^%]*%})` : use lookbehind to searching for pattern `{% for[^%]*%}`

`(?={% endfor %})` : use lookahead to searching for text `{% endfor %}`

`((?:.|\n)*)` : a message between a for loop which is captured by variable `$1`

But in case if your language do not support lookaround, you just use this

**Regex**

```
({% for[^%]*%})((?:.|\n)*)({% endfor %})
```

**Explanation**

`({% for[^%]*%})` : capture pattern `{% for[^%]*%}` to variable `$1`

`({% endfor %})` : capture  pattern `{% endfor %}` to variable `$3`

`((?:.|\n)*)` : a message between a for loop which is captured by `$2`

Just modify my `regex` according to a restriction in your language then you will done this.

**Edit**

As I search, I think `Javascript` do not support lookaround and another thing `{`, `}` need to be escape by `\`. I already tested regex using some online regex tester for Javascript and I get this.

```
(\{% for[^%]*%\})((?:.|\n)*)(\{% endfor %\})
```

to get a text that you want, you just use variable `$2`.

**Additional**

In case you want to capture message inside nested loop e.g.

**Example Message**

```
{% for product in products.pos01 %} 
    ...
    {% for product in products.pos02 %}
         "messages"
    {% endfor %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

To capture `"messages"` inside this nested loop you just need to modify my previous regex to

```
(\{% for[^%]*%\}(?:.|\n)*\{% for[^%]*%\})((?:.|\n)*)(\{% endfor %\}(?:.|\n)*\{% endfor %\})
```

**Explanation**

`(\{% for[^%]*%\}(?:.|\n)*\{% for[^%]*%\})` : means "start of for loop" following by "any characters including newline" and following by "start of for loop"

`((?:.|\n)*)`: our target message

`(\{% endfor %\}(?:.|\n)*\{% endfor %\})` : means "end of for loop" following by "any characters including newline" and following by "end of for loop"

Notice that I just rearrange my previous regex to done this little bit more complicated job.

Comment: @AlexandruRada. It means: any character `.` or `|` a new line `\n` as many as possible `(?:)*` - without grouping

Comment: what if there are multiple {% for %} loops? That's why I tried to exclude with (!?endfor) but didn't work...

Comment: You mean you want to capture them start from the most outer for loop right?

Comment: As I test, I think my regex is still working. Unless you want to specify that which level of your nested loop, that is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get what is within `{% for ... %}` and `{% endfor %}` this might work:

```
/%}([\W\w]*){%/gm
```

**Explanation**:

```
%} matches the characters %} literally
\W match any non-word character [^a-zA-Z0-9_]
\w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
{% matches the characters {% literally
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
m modifier: multi-line.
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/pM3oX7/1

<sub>It's unclear if you are wanting to get the text within the `%} {%` or also include that part.</sub>

Comment: And what if you add this text `{% if ...` to the end of atual input?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: *What if..*. yes I love that one... here, I'll give you one to use on yours `I {% forgot... what if... ewlrkjkendfor %}...and not endfor %}?` ... neat! :D